# What's the purpose of "hardLevel" in "addHardConstraintMatch"

Tags: optaplanner

For my problem, I'm using the BendableScoreHolder cause I need 3 hard constraints and 2 soft constraints. I'm wondering what's the purpose of the second parameter "hardlevel" of the method addHardConstraintMatch though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Do you need 3 *hard constraints* or 3 *hard constraints levels*?** (and similarly reasoning for soft constraints).

If you need **3 hard constraints**, you only have 1 hard level. So use `HardSoftScore`, not `BendableScore`. Note that the hard constraints might be weighted against each other. For example: `1 teacher confict` is 10 times as worse than `1 student confict`. So `1 teacher confict` is weight `-10` and `1 student confict` is weight `-1`.

If you need **3 hard constraint levels**, then `BendableScore` is indeed appropriate. The hardLevel is 1 of those 3 levels. For example: `1 teacher confict` is infinity worse than `1 student confict`. So `1 teacher confict` is level `0` and `1 student confict` is level `1`.

Comment: I need 3 hard constraint levels. Thanks :)

Comment: Another related question, how do I set up the ScoreAttainedTermination attribute in the config xml for this kind of score ? I couldn't find the answer on the doc.